# Javascript Countdown to stop at 0:00

Tags: javascript

I've found this countdown script and made some basic formatting changes but I can't figure out how to get the timer to stop at 0:00 instead of going into minus figures.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 3; 
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;

function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
}

function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
    }
}

function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}

function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs - Math.round(mins * 60);
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="timer"><font size="4"><b>You have</b></font>
    <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 16px; border: none; background-color:transparent; color: #FF0000; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"><font size="4"><b>:</b></font>
        <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 30px; border: none; background-color:transparent; color: #FF0000; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">  <font size="4"><b>to claim your free game.</b></font></div>
<script>
    countdown();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if seconds and mins are both zero and if they are return out of the Decrement function rather than calling setTimeout again.

```
function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds.value < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        console.log(seconds.value);
        if (minutes.value == 0 && seconds.value == 0) {
            return;
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
    }
}
```

I am not certain what you are going for with the < 59 condition. Try removing that logic like this:

```
function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        minutes.value = getminutes();
        seconds.value = getseconds();
        console.log(seconds.value);
        if (minutes.value == 0 && seconds.value == 0) {
            return;
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the additional line you suggested:

['code']if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            return;
        }['/code']

Comment: unfortunately not. The countdown continues into minus figures

http://jsfiddle.net/ianparks/2oggg8hy/

Comment: I have edited the above to fix the issue. You need to get the value of seconds and minutes not just the dom element. I tested the above in your fiddle and it works.

Comment: That's amazing. It works. The only issue i've noticed with this new code is if you now put the var mins = anything higher than 1 min'    the countdown gets messed up?

http://jsfiddle.net/ianparks/f6gru043/

Comment: The logic in your code seems wrong, see the latest edit I made to the answer.

Comment: Awesome !!  All working perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad algorithm to make a countdown.  Something like that would be better

```
var timeout, timer;

startChrono(3*60*1000); //3 min

function startChrono (milisec) {
  timeout = (new Date()).getTime() + milisec;

  timer = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
}

function tick () {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  var diff = now - timeout;

  if (diff <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timer); 
    diff = 0;
  }

  render(diff);
}

function render (milisec) {
  var sec = Math.floor(milisec / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(milisec / 60);
  sec = sec - (min*60);

  document.getElementById("minutes").value = sec;
  document.getElementById("seconds").value = min;
}
```